# Joomla 1.7 event registration custom component

Tags: php, events, registration, joomla1.7

I am new to `joomla`.  I have to do functionality like adding events form admin and displaying them at user end and registering users for events. One user can apply for multiple events.

Please let me know if it will be ok to make my custom component or I can get free component for event registration in `joomla 1.7`.

Also provide me link where I can learn how to develop such custom components. I googled for learning but all tutorial are very basic and limited.

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla documentation is pretty comprehensive for building a component.

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01

There are tons of event and registration extensions, but I would not recommend a free one. You are not talking about a trivial extension that you could just throw together in a couple of hours. The really good extensions are not going to be free, but the price is generally very reasonable compared to the amount of work it would take you to develop the same extension.

Event calendars - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars

Event registration - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-registration